# Gorm - Preload as deep as necessary

Tags: go, go-gorm

I'm using Gorm and have some questions as to how to retrieve nested `SubComments` from the model. The problem I'm getting is comments nested two levels deep, i.e. the `Comment.SubComments` are not loading.  Am I missing something with the `Preload`?

I also think I need a composite foreign key on Comment of `foreignKey:parent_id,parent_type`  but thats not working.

https://goplay.tools/snippet/kOhjUs7X6NQ

Here is another attempt by asteriskdev:

https://goplay.tools/snippet/jUu_W8B4cg-

You will need to run the code locally as the playground doesn't support sqlite DBs.

```
package main

import (
    "gorm.io/gorm"
    "gorm.io/gorm/clause"
)

type BlogPost struct {
    ID       uint `gorm:"primary_key"`
    Content  string
    Comments []Comment `gorm:"foreignKey:parent_id;references:id"`
}

type ParentType int

const (
    PT_BlogPost ParentType = 1
    PT_Comment             = 2
)

type Comment struct {
    ID          uint `gorm:"primary_key"`
    ParentId    uint
    ParentType  ParentType
    Comment     string
    // TODO composite foreign key not working
    SubComments []Comment `gorm:"foreignKey:parent_id,parent_type;references:id"`
}

func createComment(parentId uint, parentType ParentType) {
    switch parentType {
    case PT_BlogPost:
        var blogPost BlogPost
        // lookup blog post
        if err := models.DB.Where("id = ?", parentId).First(&blogPost).Error; err != nil {
            return
        }
        comment := Comment{
            ParentId:    parentId,
            ParentType:  PT_BlogPost,
            Comment:     "",
            SubComments: nil,
        }
        models.DB.Create(&comment)

        models.DB.Model(&blogPost).Updates(&BlogPost{
            Comments: append(blogPost.Comments, comment),
        })

    case models.PT_Comment:
        var parentComment Comment
        // lookup comment
        if err := models.DB.Where("id = ?", parentId).First(&parentComment).Error; err != nil {
            return
        }
        // Create comment and add comment to db
        comment := Comment{
            ParentId:    parentComment.ID,
            ParentType:  models.PT_Comment,
            Comment:     "",
            SubComments: nil,
        }
        models.DB.Create(&comment)
        // Append to Parent Comment and persist Parent Comment
        models.DB.Session(&gorm.Session{FullSaveAssociations: true}).Model(&parentComment).Updates(&Comment{
            SubComments: append(parentComment.SubComments, comment),
        })
    }
}

func GetCommentsForBlogPost(blogPostId uint) {
    var comments []Comment

    // Lookup Comments by BlogPostId
    **// TODO Problem is it is not returning all nested comments**
    **// i.e. The Comments.SubComments**
    if err := models.DB.Preload(clause.Associations).
        Where(&Comment{ParentType: PT_BlogPost, ParentId: blogPostId}).
        Find(&comments).Error; err != nil {
        return
    }
}
```

Trying to create an index on ParentId and ParentType and setting that as the foreign key does not work either:

```
type Comment struct {
    ID          uint `gorm:"primary_key"`
    ParentId    uint `gorm:"index:idx_parent"`
    ParentType  ParentType `gorm:"index:idx_parent"`
    Comment     string
    // TODO composite foreign key not working
    SubComments []Comment `gorm:"foreignKey:idx_parent"`
}
```

I get an error on the commented line below:
`invalid field found for struct Comment's field SubComments: define a valid foreign key for relations or implement the Valuer/Scanner interface`

```
type CreateBlogPostInput struct {
    Title   string `json:"title" binding:"required"`
    Content string `json:"content" binding:"required"`
}

func CreateBlogPost(input CreateBlogPostInput) {
    var input CreateBlogPostInput

    // Create blog post
    blogPost := models.BlogPost{
        Title:    input.Title,
        Content:  input.Content,
        Comments: []models.Comment{},
    }

    // ***Foreign key error here***
    models.DB.Create(&blogPost)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

EDIT:

This is what I came up with to get you going in the right direction.  Now that I've sat down with it, I don't know if preloading is what you want.  It depends on how many levels deep you need to go weather it will start to get cumbersome or not.  You don't need any composite keys or to even explicitly declare relationships.  The way this is written, using GORM naming convention, the relationships are inferred.

Use the pure go sqlite driver and use a logger for GORM

```
import (
    "errors"
    "log"
    "strings"
    "time"

    "github.com/glebarez/sqlite" // Use the pure go sqlite driver
    "gorm.io/gorm"
    "gorm.io/gorm/clause"
    "gorm.io/gorm/logger" // you need a logger for gorm
)
```

Your implementation switches on `ParentType` so I kept it.

```
type ParentType int

const (
    PT_BlogPost ParentType = iota
    PT_Comment
)
```

You need a live database connection.  Look to see if there is one and return it, if not create one and return it.

```
var dB *gorm.DB

// DB returns a live database connection
func DB() *gorm.DB {
    var database *gorm.DB
    var err error
    if dB == nil {
        database, err = gorm.Open(sqlite.Open("test.db"), &gorm.Config{
            Logger: logger.Default.LogMode(logger.Info), // you need a logger if you are going to do this.
            NowFunc: func() time.Time {
                return time.Now().Local() // timestamps
            },
        })
        if err != nil {
            panic("Failed to connect to database!")

        }
        dB = database
    }
    return dB

}
```

Because `BlogPost` has a `Comments []Comment` field and `Comment` has a `BlogPostID` field GORM infers the relationship.  One `BlogPost` can have many `Comment` One `Comment` can have many Sub`Comment`s.

```
// BlogPost describes a blog post
type BlogPost struct {
    ID       uint `gorm:"primaryKey"`
    Title    string
    Content  string
    Comments []Comment
}
```

A `Comment` can have a BlogPostID that refers to the BlogPost it is associated with. It can also have a CommentID. GORM infers the relationship.  GORM reads `BlogPostID` as `BlogPost.ID`.  `CommentID` as `Comment.ID`.  The `TopLevelID` will contain the top most `Comment` `ID`.  If the `Comment` is the top level `Comment`, `TopLevelID` will contain its own `ID`.  The idea here is every `Comment` knows its top level `Comment`'s `ID`.

```
// associations are applied due to the naming convention eg. BlogPostID refers to BlogPost.ID, CommentID refers to Comment.ID
type Comment struct {
    ID                uint `gorm:"primaryKey"`
    Comment           string
    BlogPostID        *uint // if this is attached to a blogpost, the blogpost ID will be here otherwise nil
    Depth             uint
    TopLevelCommentID uint
    CommentID         *uint // if this is attached to a comment, the comment ID will be here otherwise nil
    SubComments       []Comment // SubComments will be here based on BlogPostID or CommentID if SubComments are preloaded
}
```

Constructor for a new `BlogPost`

```
// NewBlogPost instantiates and returns a *BlogPost
func NewBlogPost(title, content string) *BlogPost {
    return &BlogPost{
        Title:   title,
        Content: content,
    }
}
```

Creating a comment
Here, you have to save before updating in order to know what the `ID` of the `Comment` is to set `TopLevelCommentID`.  This function will handle associating `Comment`s with `BlogPost`s or other `Comment`s depending on which parent it is being attached to.  Every comment knows its `Depth`.  Every time a new comment is created, the comment with the highest depth is added to the top level `Comment`s `Depth`  `Depth` is used to determine the number of `".SubComment"`s to add to the Preload() GORM method.

```
// New comment instantiates and returns a new comment associated with its parent
func NewComment(parentId uint, parentType ParentType, comment string) (*Comment, error) {
    // Create comment
    c := Comment{
        BlogPostID:  &parentId,
        Comment:     comment,
        SubComments: nil,
    }

    switch parentType {
    case PT_BlogPost:
        blogPost := BlogPost{}
        // lookup blog post
        if err := DB().Preload("Comments").Preload(clause.Associations).Where("id = ?", parentId).First(&blogPost).Error; err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        blogPost.Comments = append(blogPost.Comments, c)
        DB().Session(&gorm.Session{FullSaveAssociations: true}).Save(&c)
        DB().Model(&c).UpdateColumn("top_level_comment_id", c.ID)
        blogPost.Comments = append(blogPost.Comments, c)

        return &c, nil

    case PT_Comment:
        parentComment := Comment{}
        // lookup comment
        if err := DB().Preload("SubComments").Preload(clause.Associations).Where("id = ?", parentId).First(&parentComment).Error; err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }

        topComment := Comment{}
        if err := DB().Where("id = ?", parentComment.TopLevelCommentID).First(&topComment).Error; err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        topComment.Depth++
        if err := DB().Model(&topComment).UpdateColumn("depth", topComment.Depth).First(&topComment).Error; err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }

        // Create comment and add comment to db
        c.TopLevelCommentID = parentComment.TopLevelCommentID
        parentComment.SubComments = append(parentComment.SubComments, c)

        return &parentComment.SubComments[len(parentComment.SubComments)-1], nil

    }
    return nil, errors.New("fell through parent type switch")
}
```

These are methods to finalize the save to the database.

```
// Create inserts the record in the DB
func (bp *BlogPost) Create() (*BlogPost, error) {

    if err := DB().Create(&bp).Error; err != nil {
        return &BlogPost{}, err
    }
    return bp, nil
}

// Save saves a parent comment and all child associations to the database
func (c *Comment) Save() (*Comment, error) {
    if err := DB().Session(&gorm.Session{FullSaveAssociations: true}).Save(c).Error; err != nil {
        return c, errors.New("error saving comment to db")
    }
    return c, nil

}
```

Create a `BlogPost` and 7 nested `Comment`s.
Loop over them recursively and print out every `Comment` you find.

```
func main() {

    DB().AutoMigrate(&BlogPost{})
    DB().AutoMigrate(&Comment{})
    // blogpost
    bp, err := NewBlogPost("BlogPostTitle", "BlogPostContent").Create()
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("error creating blogpost", err)
    }
    // top level comment under blogpost
    c, err := NewComment(bp.ID, PT_BlogPost, "top level comment")
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("error creating top level comment", err)
    }
    c, err = c.Save()
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("error creating top level comment", err)
    }

    c, err = NewComment(c.ID, PT_Comment, "second level comment")
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("error creating second level comment", err)
    }
    c, err = c.Save()
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("error creating second level comment", err)
    }

    c, err = NewComment(c.ID, PT_Comment, "third level comment")
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("error creating third level comment", err)
    }
    c, err = c.Save()
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("error creating third level comment", err)
    }
    c, err = NewComment(c.ID, PT_Comment, "fourth level comment")
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("error creating fourth level comment", err)
    }
    c, err = c.Save()
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("error creating fourth level comment", err)
    }
    c, err = NewComment(c.ID, PT_Comment, "fifth level comment")
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("error creating fifth level comment", err)
    }
    _, err = c.Save()
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("error creating fifth level comment", err)
    }
    c, err = NewComment(c.ID, PT_Comment, "sixth level comment")
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("error creating sixth level comment", err)
    }
    _, err = c.Save()
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("error creating sixth level comment", err)
    }
    c, err = NewComment(c.ID, PT_Comment, "seventh level comment")
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("error creating seventh level comment", err)
    }
    _, err = c.Save()
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("error creating seventh level comment", err)
    }

    for _, v := range bp.GetComments() {
        commentID := uint(0)
        blogPostID := uint(0)
        if v.BlogPostID != nil {
            blogPostID = *v.BlogPostID
        }
        if v.CommentID != nil {
            commentID = *v.CommentID
        }
        log.Printf("\n\nID: %d\nComment: %s\nCommentID: %d\nBlogpostID: %d\n", v.ID, v.Comment, commentID, blogPostID)
        if v.SubComments != nil {
            subComments := v.SubComments
        nextLevel:
            for _, v := range subComments {
                commentID := uint(0)
                blogPostID := uint(0)
                if v.BlogPostID != nil {
                    blogPostID = *v.BlogPostID
                }
                if v.CommentID != nil {
                    commentID = *v.CommentID
                }
                log.Printf("\n\nID: %d\nComment: %s\nCommentID: %d\nBlogpostID: %d\n", v.ID, v.Comment, commentID, blogPostID)
                if v.SubComments != nil {
                    subComments = v.SubComments
                    goto nextLevel // I use gotos to indicate recursion
                }

            }
        }
    }

}
```

This of course is only an example,  Hope it helps.

Full source code:

```
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "log"
    "strings"
    "time"

    "github.com/glebarez/sqlite"
    "gorm.io/gorm"
    "gorm.io/gorm/clause"
    "gorm.io/gorm/logger"
)

type ParentType int

const (
    PT_BlogPost ParentType = iota
    PT_Comment
)

var dB *gorm.DB

// DB returns a live database connection
func DB() *gorm.DB {
    var database *gorm.DB
    var err error
    if dB == nil {
        database, err = gorm.Open(sqlite.Open("test.db"), &gorm.Config{
            Logger: logger.Default.LogMode(logger.Info), // you need a logger if you are going to do this.
            NowFunc: func() time.Time {
                return time.Now().Local() // timestamps
            },
        })
        if err != nil {
            panic("Failed to connect to database!")

        }
        dB = database
    }
    return dB

}

// NewBlogPost instantiates and returns a *BlogPost
func NewBlogPost(title, content string) *BlogPost {
    return &BlogPost{
        Title:   title,
        Content: content,
    }
}

// BlogPost describes a blog post
type BlogPost struct {
    ID       uint `gorm:"primaryKey"`
    Title    string
    Content  string
    Comments []Comment
}

// Create inserts the record in the DB
func (bp *BlogPost) Create() (*BlogPost, error) {

    if err := DB().Create(&bp).Error; err != nil {
        return &BlogPost{}, err
    }
    return bp, nil
}

// GetComments retrieves comments and sub comments associated with a BlogPost
func (bp *BlogPost) GetComments() []Comment {
    blogPost := BlogPost{}
    sb := strings.Builder{}
    sb.WriteString("Comments.SubComments")

    err := DB().Preload("Comments").Find(&blogPost).Error
    if err != gorm.ErrRecordNotFound {
        Depth := uint(0)
        for _, c := range blogPost.Comments {
            if c.Depth > Depth {
                Depth = c.Depth
            }
        }
        i := uint(1)
        for i < Depth {
            sb.WriteString(".SubComments")
            i++
        }
    }
    DB().
        Preload(sb.String()).         // you may want to reconsider doing it with preloads. 
        Preload(clause.Associations). // also, you will accumulate tech debt as these structures get larger.
        First(&blogPost) // .Error

    return blogPost.Comments

}

// New comment instantiates and returns a new comment associated with its parent
func NewComment(parentId uint, parentType ParentType, comment string) (*Comment, error) {
    // Create comment
    c := Comment{
        BlogPostID:  &parentId,
        Comment:     comment,
        SubComments: nil,
    }

    switch parentType {
    case PT_BlogPost:
        blogPost := BlogPost{}
        // lookup blog post
        if err := DB().Preload("Comments").Preload(clause.Associations).Where("id = ?", parentId).First(&blogPost).Error; err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        blogPost.Comments = append(blogPost.Comments, c)
        DB().Session(&gorm.Session{FullSaveAssociations: true}).Save(&c)
        DB().Model(&c).UpdateColumn("top_level_comment_id", c.ID)
        blogPost.Comments = append(blogPost.Comments, c)

        return &c, nil

    case PT_Comment:
        parentComment := Comment{}
        // lookup comment
        if err := DB().Preload("SubComments").Preload(clause.Associations).Where("id = ?", parentId).First(&parentComment).Error; err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }

        topComment := Comment{}
        if err := DB().Where("id = ?", parentComment.TopLevelCommentID).First(&topComment).Error; err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        topComment.Depth++
        if err := DB().Model(&topComment).UpdateColumn("depth", topComment.Depth).First(&topComment).Error; err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }

        // Create comment and add comment to db
        c = Comment{
            CommentID:   &parentId,
            Comment:     comment,
            SubComments: nil,
        }
        c.TopLevelCommentID = parentComment.TopLevelCommentID
        parentComment.SubComments = append(parentComment.SubComments, c)

        return &parentComment.SubComments[len(parentComment.SubComments)-1], nil

    }
    return nil, errors.New("fell through parent type switch")
}

// associations are applied due to the naming convention eg. BlogPostID refers to BlogPost.ID, CommentID refers to Comment.ID
type Comment struct {
    ID                uint `gorm:"primaryKey"`
    Comment           string
    BlogPostID        *uint // if this is attached to a blogpost, the blogpost ID will be here otherwise nil
    Depth             uint
    TopLevelCommentID uint
    CommentID         *uint // if this is attached to a comment, the comment ID will be here otherwise nil
    SubComments       []Comment // SubComments will be here based on BlogPostID or CommentID if SubComments are preloaded
}

// Save saves a parent comment and all child associations to the database
func (c *Comment) Save() (*Comment, error) {
    if err := DB().Session(&gorm.Session{FullSaveAssociations: true}).Save(c).Error; err != nil {
        return c, errors.New("error saving comment to db")
    }
    return c, nil

}

func main() {

    DB().AutoMigrate(&BlogPost{})
    DB().AutoMigrate(&Comment{})
    // blogpost
    bp, err := NewBlogPost("BlogPostTitle", "BlogPostContent").Create()
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("error creating blogpost", err)
    }
    // top level comment under blogpost
    c, err := NewComment(bp.ID, PT_BlogPost, "top level comment")
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("error creating top level comment", err)
    }
    c, err = c.Save()
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("error creating top level comment", err)
    }

    c, err = NewComment(c.ID, PT_Comment, "second level comment")
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("error creating second level comment", err)
    }
    c, err = c.Save()
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("error creating second level comment", err)
    }

    c, err = NewComment(c.ID, PT_Comment, "third level comment")
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("error creating third level comment", err)
    }
    c, err = c.Save()
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("error creating third level comment", err)
    }
    c, err = NewComment(c.ID, PT_Comment, "fourth level comment")
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("error creating fourth level comment", err)
    }
    c, err = c.Save()
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("error creating fourth level comment", err)
    }
    c, err = NewComment(c.ID, PT_Comment, "fifth level comment")
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("error creating fifth level comment", err)
    }
    _, err = c.Save()
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("error creating fifth level comment", err)
    }
    c, err = NewComment(c.ID, PT_Comment, "sixth level comment")
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("error creating sixth level comment", err)
    }
    _, err = c.Save()
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("error creating sixth level comment", err)
    }
    c, err = NewComment(c.ID, PT_Comment, "seventh level comment")
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("error creating seventh level comment", err)
    }
    _, err = c.Save()
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("error creating seventh level comment", err)
    }

    for _, v := range bp.GetComments() {
        commentID := uint(0)
        blogPostID := uint(0)
        if v.BlogPostID != nil {
            blogPostID = *v.BlogPostID
        }
        if v.CommentID != nil {
            commentID = *v.CommentID
        }
        log.Printf("\n\nID: %d\nComment: %s\nCommentID: %d\nBlogpostID: %d\n", v.ID, v.Comment, commentID, blogPostID)
        if v.SubComments != nil {
            subComments := v.SubComments
        nextLevel:
            for _, v := range subComments {
                commentID := uint(0)
                blogPostID := uint(0)
                if v.BlogPostID != nil {
                    blogPostID = *v.BlogPostID
                }
                if v.CommentID != nil {
                    commentID = *v.CommentID
                }
                log.Printf("\n\nID: %d\nComment: %s\nCommentID: %d\nBlogpostID: %d\n", v.ID, v.Comment, commentID, blogPostID)
                if v.SubComments != nil {
                    subComments = v.SubComments
                    goto nextLevel // I use gotos to indicate recursion
                }

            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What about the foreign key problem?

Comment: `SubComments []Comment \`gorm:"foreignKey:ParentId,ParentType"\` `
You were using the names of the columns in your database instead of the name of the field in the Struct you defined in your model. 
`SubComments []Comment \`gorm:"foreignKey:parent_id,parent_type;references:id"\``
 Also, you don't need to  declare references because gorm defaults to the primary key.

Comment: https://gorm.io/docs/has_many.html#Self-Referential-Has-Many

Comment: It still tells me `invalid field found for struct Comment's field SubComments: define a valid foreign key for relations or implement the Valuer/Scanner interface`.  Updated OP

Comment: It could be that you are not capitalizing both letters 'ID' in 'ParentId'.   Try changing it to 'ParentID' and try migrating again.

Comment: Nope that's not it.

Comment: Ah, I think I got it.  I edited my answer to reflect changing the primary key to a composite primary key that matches the foreign key.

Comment: No, ID needs to be the primary key. And it doesnt work if setting all 3 as primary

Comment: A referential constraint must have a one-to-one relationship between referencing and referenced columns. In other words, if the primary key is a set of columns (a composite key), then the foreign key also must be a set of columns that corresponds to the composite key.

Comment: Problem is if I set only ParentID and ParentType to be the primary key, then ID does not autoincrement even with autoincrement set.

Comment: There are two versions of gorm.  You are using v2.  You may be running into information about gorm v1 when searching for answers.  One of the breaking changes in V2 was the struct tags.  primary_key was changed to primaryKey for example.   Looking back at your original question, I noticed you are using a mixture of V1 and V2.  Check out this page, and make sure you are following the V2 convention.
https://gorm.io/docs/models.html#Fields-Tags

Comment: I updated the fields but same issues

Comment: Added a go playground link to make it easier.

Comment: Are you able to use `autoIncrement` on `ID` while using `ParentType` and `ParentID` as the composite primary key?

Comment: I tried but it doesn't increment\

Comment: I commented out what you had and replaced it with what should work.  https://goplay.tools/snippet/jUu_W8B4cg-
These questions are difficult to answer.  Often it is difficult to get a good picture of what is going on without being able to connect to the database and debug.

Comment: ugh.  still giving me foreign key errors.  could you copy the code and try locally please?

Comment: Sure.  I have to work right now though.  If you can hold on for a bit, I will try to work out what I think you are trying to achieve.  Which is a multi-threaded conversation.

Comment: https://go.dev/play/p/ddRRbExtuow

Comment: I edited my answer.  There are 3 playground links at the top.  The third one preloads as deep as necessary.

Comment: Thank you so much for the hard work.  I took a different approach because loading the subcomments is unnecessarily complex.  I  did pretty much the same thing just loading them recursively, which hits the db multiple times instead of loading in one go.

Comment: You are welcome.  Yeah, after sitting down and doing it I definitely agree with you. The first project in which I used GORM, full preloads and full association saves started to bog us down and we had to stop using them mostly.  Again, it depends on how big the models and data get.